# Redirect port 5000 OSRM a subdomain in Apache2

Tags: server, apache2, proxy, port-forwarding, reverse-proxy

**Little description**:
Redirect port 5000 to a subdomain

**Description**:
Well I have a program, "supervisor" It has a OSRM (open street routing map), It is running in ***port 5000***, I want to redirect that port to a subdomain  ***example.mywebsite.com***, all with Apache

**My SO**: is Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

**Apache version**: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

I have a file for every subdomain in : /etc/apache2/sites-available/

I want a file for my problem there...

I don't know how to do It.
This will help another, and I'm doing a tuto of installing nominatim, and osrm, with apache...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have the service running in **port 5000**, you want to show,proxy you service that is in **127.0.0.1:5000**  or in **mywebsite.com:5000** to a subdomain or domain like **osrm.mywebsite.com**  or **myosrmwebsite.com**

You'll need to **enable mod_proxy in Apache2** first. So run these commands as root, or sudo:

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
```

**Edit your hosts file**

```
# if you don't have access try with sudo
nano /etc/hosts
```

**Add entry to your hosts file**

```
# path /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 subdomainname.mywebsite.com
87.164.25.1 subdomainname.mywebsite.com
```

The `87.164.25.1` is an example of ip public it isn't real

After this **we need to go to** `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

**Create a file *.conf** for our subdomain or domain

```
nano subdomainname.mywebsite.com.conf
```

In this file we are going to **create a config to proxy our port to servername**

```
#filename 'subdomainname.mywebsite.com.conf'
#dir /etc/apache2/sites-available
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName osrm.website.com  # my subdomain or website name server
    ProxyPass               /       http://localhost:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse        /       http://localhost:5000/
    ProxyRequests     Off

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**note:** If when you try to see the website through the url, and nothing happened, try change `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost 87.164.25.1:80>` the ip that server has.

#### Add the *.conf file to apache with this command, and check the list of commands.

**To enable it**

```
sudo a2ensite subdomainname.mywebsite.com.conf
```

**To disable it**

```
sudo a2dissite subdomainname.mywebsite.com.conf
```

**To list all sites enables**

```
# if you want to know what sites are enables.. or check if it is enable
apache2ctl -S
```

**To reload apache or restart**

```
# only reload the config files without restart
sudo service apache2 reload

# restart apache
sudo service apache2 restart
```

### Websites of reference

1. [How to setup subdomain on Ubuntu Server 14.04](http://kim.sg/index.php/ubuntu/17-how-to-setup-subdomain-on-ubuntu-server-14-04)
2. [Get a list of all virtual hosts which are defined in all apache configuration files](http://www.faqforge.com/linux/controlpanels/get-a-list-of-all-virtual-hosts-which-are-defined-in-all-apache-configuration-files/)
3. [Proxy port to site - example No. 1 - https://serverfault.com/a/140161](https://serverfault.com/a/140161)
4. [Proxy port to site - example No. 2 - http://freedif.org/how-to-redirect-a-port-to-a-sub-domain-proxypass/](http://freedif.org/how-to-redirect-a-port-to-a-sub-domain-proxypass/)
5. [Proxy port to site - example No. 3 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8442270/5287072](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8442270/5287072)
6. [Proxy port to site - example No. 4 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/589479/5287072](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589368/how-to-redirect-different-sub-domain-requests-to-different-port)

*** *I put a title and url if for some reason it fail...***

Comment: Thank you!!! I followed every step and it works like a charm. I was forwarding to my SpringBoot application running at port 9582. 
Just a side note though, make sure you put a forward slash in front of your 8080 otherwise the reverse proxy would struggle.